# How to pass arguments to AppleScripts in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, applescript

I've embedded an AppleScript into my Xcode project. The script *processId.scpt* requires an argument. How can I add this when executing the script in Objective-C?

```
NSString *scriptPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"processId" ofType:@"scpt"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:scriptPath]) {
    NSURL *scriptUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:scriptPath];

    NSDictionary *error = nil;
    NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:scriptUrl error:&error];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor *result = [script executeAndReturnError:nil];

    NSData *data = [result data];
    int pid = 0;
    [data getBytes:&pid length:[data length]];

    NSLog(@"Result: %d. %@. %@.", pid, [result stringValue], [error description]);        
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're taking arguments in the script, but take a look at [this post](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/195863-accessing-script-run-handler-from-nsapplescript.html#195873) for info about creating an `AEMEvent`, attaching parameters to it, and then sending it to the script.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your base SDK setting (it would need to be at least 10.6), another option would be to add the script as an AppleScriptObjC class and call the handlers/methods like normal Objective-C.  See [this page](http://allancraig.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=148%3acalling-applescriptobjc-files-from-objective-c&catid=39%3aobjective-c&Itemid=86) for instructions (and an example project), and the [ASObjC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ScriptingAutomation/RN-AppleScriptObjC/_index.html) for naming conventions.